# The absolute uri: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this app

Tags: java, xml, spring, jsp, maven

I have problem with this error in `spring mvc`

I saw similar issues, but a wonderful thing is that i have not any `lib` folder under `WEB-INF` !

I am using `jdk 1.7` and `netbeans7` and `maven`.

Here is my project structure:

[image]

This is `pom.xml` :

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.sajjad</groupId>
    <artifactId>OnlineBookStore2</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>OnlineBookStore2</name>

    <properties>
        <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>unknown.binary</groupId>
            <artifactId>org-apache-commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>unknown.binary</groupId>
            <artifactId>cglib-2.2</artifactId>
            <version>SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>unknown.binary</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop-4.0.1.RELEASE</artifactId>
            <version>SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>unknown.binary</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aspects-4.0.1.RELEASE</artifactId>
            <version>SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>unknown.binary</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans-4.0.1.RELEASE</artifactId>
            <version>SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>unknown.binary</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-build-src-4.0.1.RELEASE</artifactId>
            <version>SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>unknown.binary</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-4.0.1.RELEASE</artifactId>
            <version>SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>unknown.binary</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support-4.0.1.RELEASE</artifactId>
            <version>SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>unknown.binary</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core-4.0.1.RELEASE</artifactId>
            <version>SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>unknown.binary</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-expression-4.0.1.RELEASE</artifactId>
            <version>SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>unknown.binary</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-framework-bom-4.0.1.RELEASE</artifactId>
            <version>SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>unknown.binary</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-instrument-4.0.1.RELEASE</artifactId>
            <version>SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>unknown.binary</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-instrument-tomcat-4.0.1.RELEASE</artifactId>
            <version>SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>unknown.binary</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc-4.0.1.RELEASE</artifactId>
            <version>SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>unknown.binary</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jms-4.0.1.RELEASE</artifactId>
            <version>SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>unknown.binary</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-messaging-4.0.1.RELEASE</artifactId>
            <version>SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>unknown.binary</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm-4.0.1.RELEASE</artifactId>
            <version>SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>unknown.binary</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-oxm-4.0.1.RELEASE</artifactId>
            <version>SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>unknown.binary</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test-4.0.1.RELEASE</artifactId>
            <version>SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>unknown.binary</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx-4.0.1.RELEASE</artifactId>
            <version>SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>unknown.binary</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web-4.0.1.RELEASE</artifactId>
            <version>SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>unknown.binary</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc-4.0.1.RELEASE</artifactId>
            <version>SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>unknown.binary</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc-portlet-4.0.1.RELEASE</artifactId>
            <version>SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>unknown.binary</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-websocket-4.0.1.RELEASE</artifactId>
            <version>SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>unknown.binary</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final</artifactId>
            <version>SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>6.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                    <compilerArguments>
                        <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                    </compilerArguments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${endorsed.dir}</outputDirectory>
                            <silent>true</silent>
                            <artifactItems>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>javax</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>javaee-endorsed-api</artifactId>
                                    <version>6.0</version>
                                    <type>jar</type>
                                </artifactItem>
                            </artifactItems>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>unknown-jars-temp-repo</id>
            <name>A temporary repository created by NetBeans for libraries and jars it could not identify. Please replace the dependencies in this repository with correct ones and delete this repository.</name>
            <url>file:${project.basedir}/lib</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
</project>
```

And this is my `web.xml` :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
            http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

And this is my `dispatcher-servlet.xml`:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<beans xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                          http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                          http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                          http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
                          http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
                          http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"> 

    <context:component-scan base-package="sajjad.htlo"/> 
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>

    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/pics/" />
    <mvc:default-servlet-handler/>

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver" id="viewResolver">
        <property name="prefix"> 
            <value>/WEB-INF/jsp/</value> 
        </property> 
        <property name="suffix"> 
            <value>.jsp</value> 
        </property> 
    </bean>
</beans>
```

My controller class:

```
@Controller
public class IndexController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/index.html")
    public ModelAndView indexPage() {
        return new ModelAndView("index");
    }
}
```

My view `jsp` file:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Welcome</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        this is index page
        <img src="resources/pics/t3.jpg" />
    </body>
</html>
```

When i try : `http://localhost:8080/OnlineBookStore2/index.html` This error happens:

```
HTTP Status 500 - The absolute uri: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: The absolute uri: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application
org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.jspError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:56)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.dispatch(ErrorDispatcher.java:445)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.jspError(ErrorDispatcher.java:117)
...
```

I am going to access image from `jsp` file.

**UPDATE**

I created `lib` folder under `WEB-INF` and put `jstl-1.2.jar` on it, as you can see in the picture:

[image]

But i have the same problem yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add the `jstl` tag library to the `WEB-INF/lib` folder. if you don't have one you make the `lib` folder.

More on `jstl` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info)

Also add it to your maven dependencies

Comment: See `UPDATE` section.

Comment: It may be because you have your jsp's in `WEB-INF/jsp` as far as I know the jsp's should be 1 level above `WEB-INF` in your case you `Web Pages` folder

Comment: How can i add a folder to maven?

Comment: Not the folder, the library. Have you moved the jsp's to you `Web pages` folder?

Comment: And i declared `jst1` dependency to maven and maven download it automatically. as @Neil McGuigan says.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the jstl tag library to the WEB-INF/lib folder. if you don't have one you make the lib folder.
Download JAR from 
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/jstl/1.2

Adding Maven Dependency Does Not Work.

Answer (score 0):

In your Maven POM, in the `<dependencies>` section, add

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had got the library on pom, but with scope as `provided`.

In that case, we need to add the library on your server, maybe `/lib` or in your proyect `WEB-INF/lib`

On the other hand, we can remove that scope.

Answer (score 0):

Very simple to fix. In Netbeans left click your project, click properties, choose libraries and there click "add library". There you choose "JSTL 1.2.1" and click the new "add library" in the dialog.

Answer (score 0):

Please Add this dependency im pom.xml.

```
         <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: add this dependency in which file ?

Comment: In pom.xml file if it is maven project.